# An operator $T:\mathbb{R}^4\to \mathbb{R}^4$ such that $T$ has no (real) eigenvalues.

Tags: linear-algebra

Give an example of an operator $T:\mathbb{R}^4\to \mathbb{R}^4$ such that $T$ has no (real) eigenvalues.

How can I find this operator?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First, find a polynomial of degree 4 with no real roots. Then form the companion matrix of this polynomial (look up "companion matrix" if you are not familiar with this term - you'll be glad you did).

Answer (score 8):

Consider a rotation about the origin.

Comment: ... or two rotations, on ${\mathbb R}^2$ and ${\mathbb R}^2$.

Comment: think about block multiplication.

Comment: @Potato, What is the definition of rotation for $\mathbb{R}^4$? Thanks.

Comment: An orthogonal matrix with determinant 1. For the purposes of constructing your example, use @RobertIsrael's hint.

Answer (score 7):

A simple example is the linear operator corresponding to $ \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
 \end{array} \right) $

Comment: This does not correspond to a linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}^4$ to itself!

Comment: Quite right.  Very late.  It has been fixed.

Answer (score 5):

Another angle to look at this problem is to take the differential equation $(D^2+1)^2[y]=0$
  (or $y''''+2y''+y=0$ if you prefer) and reduce it to a system of four first order ODEs by reduction of order $x_1=y,x_2=y',x_3=y'',x_4=y'''$. The matrix of this system of ODEs will have complex eigenvalues $i,-i$ corresponding to a pair of complex e-vectors and a pair of generalized complex e-vectors. This is the *complementary* matrix to the ODE.

$$ \left[ \begin{array}{cccc}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
-1 & 0 & -2 & 0 
\end{array} \right] $$

This matrix corresponds to $T: \mathbb{R}^4 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^4$ with no real e-values.

Comment: This is essentially the companion matrix for the quartic $(x^2+1)^2$.

Answer (score 1):

You can construct examples by doing the following:

1. Choose any diagonal matrix with non-real values on it's diagonal:

$
 A =
 \begin{pmatrix}
  a_{1,1} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & a_{2,2} & 0 & 0 \\
  0  & 0  & a_{3,3} & 0  \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & a_{4,4}
 \end{pmatrix}
$

By choosing correctly $M \in GL(4,\mathbb C)$, you can make the operator $T=M^{-1}AM$ real: $T : \mathbb R^4 \longrightarrow \mathbb R^4$.

Comment: These examples are incorrect, for this is not a $T:\mathbb{R}^4\to\mathbb{R}^4$.

Comment: Not necessarily you can solve linear equations and make your operator real by choosing correctly the entries of $M$.

Comment: sure, but you said to choose "any".

Comment: Okay, you *can*. But then you need to prove this. More specifically, you would have to give an example or otherwise prove the existence of such $M$. Your answer is not very helpful like this. You translated the problem of finding $T$ to a much harder question of finding the right $M$.

Comment: I don't think I believe this. It seems to imply that given any 4 complex numbers there's a quartic polynomial with real coefficients (the characteristic polynomial of $T$) with those 4 numbers as roots.